# Making rejection comments mandatory in approval processes

Tags: approval-process, before-trigger, comments

I need to make Approval rejection comments mandatory, to do that i am using a trigger suggsted by Mr. Christopher , that was working fine if the user does not given the comments, but the issue is trigger is firing when the user has given the comments, posting my code here

```
trigger TR_Reject_Approval_Comments on TR_Currency_Approval__c(before update) 
{

  Map<Id, TR_Currency_Approval__c> rejectedStatements = new Map<Id, TR_Currency_Approval__c>{};

  for(TR_Currency_Approval__c cur: trigger.new)
  {

    TR_Currency_Approval__c oldCur = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(cur.Id);

    if (oldCur.Approval_Status__c != 'Rejected' && cur.Approval_Status__c == 'Rejected')
    { 
      rejectedStatements.put(cur.Id, cur);  
    }
  }




  if (!rejectedStatements.isEmpty())  
  {

    List<Id> processInstanceIds = new List<Id>{};

    for (TR_Currency_Approval__c curn : [SELECT 
                                         (SELECT ID FROM ProcessInstances ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
                                      FROM TR_Currency_Approval__c WHERE ID IN :rejectedStatements.keySet()])

    {
        processInstanceIds.add(curn.ProcessInstances[0].Id);
    }

    for (ProcessInstance pi : [SELECT TargetObjectId,
                                   (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1 )
                               FROM ProcessInstance WHERE Id IN :processInstanceIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]) 



    {                     
      if ((pi.Steps[0].Comments == null || 
           pi.Steps[0].Comments.trim().length() == 0))
      {
        rejectedStatements.get(pi.TargetObjectId).addError('Please provide a rejection reason!');
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing any mistake,or suggest me any other ways to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter steps by value "Rejected". As you are getting all steps with ProcessInstance object there can be steps without comments.

A query would be narrowed down to:

```
[SELECT TargetObjectId,
       (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps WHERE StepStatus='Rejected' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1 )
FROM ProcessInstance WHERE Id IN :processInstanceIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]
```

You can even filter the `ProcessInstance` object by Status as:

```
[SELECT 
      (SELECT ID FROM ProcessInstances WHERE Status='Rejected' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM TR_Currency_Approval__c WHERE ID IN :rejectedStatements.keySet()]
```